# Rails deleting photo gallery photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using:

- Rails 4.0.1
- paperclip 3.5.2

I managed to create an image gallery. With model PlaceGallery for Place model. There is no controller for PlaceGallery and i don't know how to delete this images in gallery. I mage a checkbox and etc, but when i updating places it ust duplicates missing images. What should i add to my place controller?

```
**place.rb**
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :place_galleries, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :place_galleries, :allow_destroy => true

end

**place_gallery.rb**
class PlaceGallery < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :place
has_attached_file :image

end

**places_controller.rb**
class PlacesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @place = Place.new
  (3 - @place.place_galleries.length).times { @place.place_galleries.build }
end

def edit
  @place = Place.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
  (3 - @place.place_galleries.length).times { @place.place_galleries.build }
end

private
def set_place
  @place = Place.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
end

def place_params
  params.require(:place).permit(:title, :slug, :user_id, :place_type_id, :content, :address, :place_photo, place_galleries_attributes: :image)
end
end

**_form.html.erb** for Place
   <%= f.fields_for :place_galleries do |pg| %>
     <% if pg.object.new_record? %> 
       <%= pg.file_field :image %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.fields_for :place_galleries do |pg| %>
     <% unless pg.object.new_record? %> 
       <%= link_to(image_tag(pg.object.image.url(:small)), pg.object.image.url(:large))%>
       <%= pg.check_box :_destroy %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

[image: Before updating. 2 checkboxes checked, so 2 photos should destroy, am i right?]
[image: Some black magic happened here and 2 photos didn't delte, only duplicated 2 missing photos, but 1 uploaded photo uploaded right]

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by adding params :id and :_destroy to my places_controller.rb

```
def place_params
  params.require(:place).permit(:title, :slug, :user_id, :place_type_id, :content, :address, :place_photo, place_galleries_attributes: [:image, :id, :_destroy])
end
```

That's the answer.

If you don't know how to make an image gallery try this - http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads and use my edits if you running rails 4.

Thanks to all. Good luck!